# Eclipse CDT headless build from cygwin terminal issues

Tags: cygwin, eclipse-cdt

Are there any tutorials on doing a headless build from the command line that are more specific than https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/advanced/headless-builds/. I am having some issues following this tutorial. [Headless build example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNg5v.png)

I am getting an error -> eclipse: command not found when I follow the tutorial. I am also unsure of what the configuration I am supposed to enter is in the last line. Any help is very  appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The eclipse that is not found is the eclipse you downloaded/installed. You may need to run with the full path to eclipse for it to find eclipse itself.